# Restore my code with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a this HTML structure:

```
<div class="footer--columns block-group">
  <div class="st--footer-column">
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a javascript code that will perform the following result:

```
    let sts = $(".st--footer-column");

    for (let i of sts) {
        while (i.childElementCount) {
            i.parentNode.appendChild(i.firstElementChild)
        }
        i.parentNode.removeChild(i)
    }
```

Result:

```
<div class="footer--columns block-group">
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
</div>
```

now, I need the code, which will change my result back to the first code with div `st--footer-column`

Comment: So make a div with the class matching the element you removed, append those children to it, and then append that child to the original parent?  What about this is confusing you?

Comment: What are you stuck on? It's great that you need something but show what you've attempted already to achieve that so we can help.

Comment: Don't worry JsStorm2, we can't all be as clever as Taplar. Welcome to Stack Overflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @andydavies it's not about being clever.  It's about being aware of when a question is a code request question, and not asking about a specific issue.  I've asked the user to state what trouble they are having in doing this themselves.  Their difficulty to do this themselves, *is the real question*.  Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135049/encouraging-users-to-try-something-before-asking-write-me-code-that-questio/135051#135051

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method instead. Instead of using a `for` loop to iterate through the children of the `div`, you can just append the [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) of the `div` to its `parent()` after detaching it.

The documentation states that:

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

```css
.st--footer-column{
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer--columns block-group">
  <div class="st--footer-column">
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
    <div class="footer--column column--menu block">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="detach">
Detach
</button>
<button id="reattach">
Attach
</button>
<script>
let detachedsts, stscontents, stsparent;
$('#detach').click(function(e){
if(!detachedsts){
let sts = $(".st--footer-column");
stsparent = sts.parent();
stscontents = sts.contents();
detachedsts = sts.detach();
stsparent.append(stscontents);
}
});
$('#reattach').click(function(e){
  if(detachedsts){
    detachedsts.append(stscontents)
    stsparent.empty().append(detachedsts);
    detachedsts = null;
  }
});
</script>
```